# JS Array in JSON by Mongoose Schema

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongoose, mongoose-schema

The problem that I cant get access to array in array. Here is my Mongoose Schema:

```
const newSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email            : String,
    name              : String,
    array : [Number]
})
```

And here is data, which I put in array:

```
{
  "array": [
    -11,
    "10,10,0",
    "1"
  ]
}
```

Now I am trying to update the value "10" in the second row like this:

```
newAccount.array[3,0] = parseInt(someVariable)
```

or like this

```
newAccount.array[3][0] = parseInt(someVariable)
```

But the value doesn't changing in any case. How can I change it correctly?

Comment: Your schema has an array of type Number but you have strings in your data. Also, are you trying to update "10" within "10,10,0"? ...this is a string not an array

Comment: Can you show one of the valid JSON record that holds against the schema?

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick and dirty solution for your problem:

```
var obj = {
    array: [
        -11,
        '10,0,0',
        12
    ]
}
// splitting by ',' char
const newArray = obj.array[1].split(',')
// enter your new variable here.
newArray[0] = parseInt(someVariable);
// join them together so that we have the old structure back.
obj.array[1] = newArray.join(',');

console.log(obj);
```

a better approach would be to restructure your data enrichment in that way, that you don't have mixed types in there.

**and the outcome:**

[image]